# linear fit with predefined error in response variable

Tags: python, r, statistics, linear-regression, data-fitting

I have the following dataset (replication):

```
ordinal_var    fraction    error_on_fraction
1              1.2         0.1
2              0.87        0.23
4              1.12        0.11
5              0.75        0.06
5              0.66        0.15
6              0.98        0.08
7              1.34        0.05
7              2.86        0.12
```

Now I want to do linear regression analysis (preferably in R but python is also fine) were I pass the error in y for each point within the formula. So in R this would be something like (for better understanding of the question):

```
lm(fraction +-error_on_fraction ~ ordinal_var, data = dataset)
```

Of course I tried to find how to do it myself first but I can't find an answer.
For previous analysis with error on x and y I just the scipy.odr library but I can't find how to do it with only an error in the y(response) variable.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: for step 1 you must use factor(ordinal_var,order=T)

Comment: `lm(ordinal_var ~ fraction + error_on_fraction , data = dataset)` ?

Comment: [related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235693/linear-model-where-the-data-has-uncertainty-using-r#235731)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a simple weighted least squares model.

### Sample data

Let's read in your sample data.

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "ordinal_var    fraction    error_on_fraction
1              1.2         0.1
2              0.87        0.23
4              1.12        0.11
5              0.75        0.06
5              0.66        0.15
6              0.98        0.08
7              1.34        0.05
7              2.86        0.12", header = T)
```

### Weighted least squares model

We fit a weighted linear model of the form `fraction ~ ordered(ordinal_var)`, where the `weights` are given by `1 / error_on_fraction`.

```
fit <- lm(
    fraction ~ ordered(ordinal_var),
    weights = 1 / error_on_fraction,
    data = df)
summary(fit)
#    
#Call:
#lm(formula = fraction ~ ordered(ordinal_var), data = df, weights = 1/error_on_fraction)
#
#Weighted Residuals:
#         1          2          3          4          5          6          7
# 2.220e-16 -1.851e-16 -1.753e-17  1.050e-01 -1.660e-01  1.810e-17 -1.999e+00
#         8
# 3.097e+00
#
#Coefficients:
#                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)              1.1136     0.3365   3.309   0.0804 .
#ordered(ordinal_var).L   0.3430     0.7847   0.437   0.7047
#ordered(ordinal_var).Q   0.6228     0.7057   0.883   0.4706
#ordered(ordinal_var).C   0.2794     0.8920   0.313   0.7838
#ordered(ordinal_var)^4   0.2127     0.9278   0.229   0.8400
#ordered(ordinal_var)^5  -0.2469     0.7916  -0.312   0.7846
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 2.61 on 2 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.5427,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.6004
#F-statistic: 0.4748 on 5 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.783
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! It looks clear to me what you are doing. The only question I have is why for the weights you divide 1 by the error?

Comment: @Jonas The weight should be inversely proportional to the error (or error squared), in order for measurements with a *smaller* error to carry *more* weight. Whether you consider `1 / error_on_fraction` or `1 / error_on_fraction^2` depends on whether you consider the inverse standard error or variance as a weighting factor. I would say using the variance is actually the more popular choice, i.e. `1 / error_on_fraction^2`.

Comment: Ah oke that makes sense! Thanks a lot for the reply. I'll accept this as the answer :)